# Pandas Dataframe pd.to_datetime is formatting dates completly wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to read a csv file which has multiple dates in this format:

```
dd.mm.yyyy, HH:MM:SS

02.10.2019, 07:04:07
```

and if im using this:

```
df['Zeitpunkt']=pd.to_datetime(df['Zeitpunkt'])
```

the date is formatting wrong, but thats not the problem the code makes a wrong date like for example

```
12.09.2019, 07:04:07
```

the code makes it to

```
2019-12-09 07:04:07
```

but on other dates mostly it does from this:

```
02.10.2019, 07:04:07
```

to this:

```
2019-02-10 07:04:07
```

and i can't format it because i need to split it in days

Could somebody help me?

Comment: `to_datetime` can't read your mind. You have to use the `format` argument in this case https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Zeitpunkt'], dayfirst=True)`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Zeitpunkt'], format='%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S)` if you want to be 100% sure (and if you're sure the format is constant)